# Athena Query - mismatched input 'CASE'. Expecting: '%', '*', '+', '-', '.', '/', 'AND', 'AT' ETC

Tags: amazon-athena

```sql
select
line_item_line_item_type,
DATE_FORMAT((bill_billing_period_start_date), '%y-%m-%d') as Billing_Date,
line_item_product_code,
resource_tags_user_map_migrated,
line_item_usage_account_id,
Sum(line_item_unblended_cost) as Unblended_Cost
from billing_reports_lzmaster
WHERE
year(bill_billing_period_start_date)=2023 and month(bill_billing_period_start_date) IN (8)
AND
resource_tags_user_map_migrated = 'mig31338' OR resource_tags_user_map_migrated = 'mig_31338' or resource_tags_user_map_migrated = 'mig_ec2_31332' AND
resource_tags_user_map_migrated <> ''
CASE WHEN line_item_unblended_cost > '0'
Group by
line_item_line_item_type,
DATE_FORMAT((bill_billing_period_start_date), '%y-%m-%d'),
line_item_product_code,
product_product_name,
line_item_resource_id,
resource_tags_user_map_migrated,
line_item_usage_account_id,
product_product_name
```

Comment: And what is the purpose for this `case` is? Please share some description of what you are trying to achieve, ideally a [mre] with sample data and desired output.